# Can an article talk and read?

Tags: word-usage

Can I write like this:

> The same **article**, **talking** about the engines made by the manufacturer Glenn Hammond Curtis, **reads**: 
>   "They are one of the most practical air-cooled motors built in this country."

Comment: Absolutely. Words speak, even though they are read.

Comment: See [*talk about*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/talk+about): "3. to have thorough or specialized knowledge". If you take out that phrase, then "The same article reads..." is clearly OK.

Answer (score 2):

This is a normal use of the verbs "to talk" and "to read" with written documents.

> The article I read just now *talks about* NASA's mission to explore an asteroid near Jupiter.
>
> One of J.K. Rowling's latest tweets *reads*: "I seem to have woken up in the 90s."

You can also use "to say":

> Her letter *says* that she will be coming home in a week.

And various other verbs:

> Her latest book *tells* us about her early life among sheepherders.
>
> His poems really *speak* to me.
>
> Every hour this news feed *reports* the location of the tagged pod of whales.

and many more.